# Unserializing complex PHP object from Laravel queue in Python

Tags: python, json, laravel, serialization, hook

I am trying to get the ID of the item stored in this Laravel queue message. I am using Python and the library phpserialize.

This is the string:

```
'O:26:"App\\Jobs\\GetMatchReportJob":12:{s:10:"\x00*\x00patient";O:45:"Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\ModelIdentifier":4:{s:5:"class";s:11:"App\\Patient";s:2:"id";i:3;s:9:"relations";a:0:{}s:10:"connection";s:5:"pgsql";}s:5:"tries";i:3;s:10:"retryAfter";i:30;s:7:"timeout";i:25;s:10:"connection";N;s:5:"queue";s:14:"optimas-result";s:15:"chainConnection";N;s:10:"chainQueue";N;s:5:"delay";N;s:10:"middleware";a:0:{}s:7:"chained";a:0:{}s:6:"\x00*\x00job";N;}'
```

As you can see, I have an object within an object.

I'm trying to create an object hook, like this:

```
class Patient(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

def object_hook(data, d):
    cls = {'App\Jobs\GetMatchReportJob': Patient}['Illuminate\Contracts\Database\ModelIdentifier']
    return cls(**d)
```

Obviously, this is wrong. How can create a object hook to retrieve an object within an object?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I face similar issue - (still trying to fix it completly) but I hope this helps someone out there.
Use object_hook=ChainMap

Example :

```
from phpserialize import loads
from collections import ChainMap, UserDict, namedtuple, Counter, OrderedDict, 
defaultdict, deque, UserList, UserString
data = loads(b'O:26:"App\\Jobs\\GetMatchReportJob":12:{s:10:"\x00*\x00patient";O:45:"Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\ModelIdentifier":4:{s:5:"class";s:11:"App\\Patient";s:2:"id";i:3;s:9:"relations";a:0:{}s:10:"connection";s:5:"pgsql";}s:5:"tries";i:3;s:10:"retryAfter";i:30;s:7:"timeout";i:25;s:10:"connection";N;s:5:"queue";s:14:"optimas-result";s:15:"chainConnection";N;s:10:"chainQueue";N;s:5:"delay";N;s:10:"middleware";a:0:{}s:7:"chained";a:0:{}s:6:"\x00*\x00job";N;}', object_hook=ChainMap)
print(data)
print(data.maps)
```

Comment: Are you saying that your solution is not working correctly but you post it anyways?

Comment: it works correctly for this case and this is not my actual solution. I just gave an example.